# How to implement code review for ARM templates using Visual Studio Code and VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-rm-template, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working with ARM templates; I've developed ARM templates for virtual machines, SQL server, storage account and service bus, etc.

I want to implement the code review for the above ARM templates. So, an anyone suggest to me how to implement the code review for ARM templates using Visual Studio Code and VSTS?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Create a repository to store your ARM templates.

Configure your master branch with branch policies:

[image]

You get there from the list of branches. Click on the context menu for the master branch.

Connect your Visual Studio Code to your repository.
Now for every work you have to create a new branch (topic/feature branch) and then, when your work is done, create a pull request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/pull-requests?view=vsts